# replace strings in dataframe that match strings in matrix

Tags: r, string, matrix, replace, match

I have a dataframe `df` with a series of NA and strings and 2 matrices `match` and `value` with same `ncol` and `nrow`. `match` has all the possible strings in `df`

I would like to replace the strings in `df` with those in `value`. If a string in `df` matches the values in `match`, then it can be replaced by the string in `value` **at the same position**

I believe the first step is to create a new df with the position of match in df

```
df1 <- which(df %in% match) #nothing valuable...
```

apologies for less code from my side.

---

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("ab","bc",NA,"aa",NA,NA,"de","aa",NA,"bc","ab","ab"),ncol = 4))
match <- matrix(c("ab","bc","de","aa"),nrow = 2)
value <- matrix(c("Good","Bad","Average","Stop"),nrow = 2)
```

---

```
 output <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("Good","Bad",NA,"Stop",NA,NA,"Average","Stop",NA,"Bad","Good","Good"),ncol = 4))
```

Comment: Or using `plyr` : `matrix(mapvalues(unlist(df),c(match),c(value)),dim(df))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `unlist` the dataframe and `match` the elements of dataframe with that of `m1` and use the index to get corresponding value from `value`.

```
df[] <- value[match(unlist(df), m1)]
df

#    V1   V2      V3   V4
#1 Good Stop Average  Bad
#2  Bad <NA>    Stop Good
#3 <NA> <NA>    <NA> Good
```

Note : Renamed `match` as `m1`.

Comment: simple and clear. in order to add a nomatch in case i want to keep the string. adding  'df[] <- value[match(unlist(df), m1,nomatch=unlist(df))]' does not keep the previous ones. any ideas? thanks.

Comment: @Chrisftw I didn't get you. `to keep the string` ?? do you mean an empty string instead of `NA`'s?. What output you aiming at ?

Comment: your answer is correct. In case some strings in `df` do not match the strings in `values` , i would like to add a `nomatch` argument that will keep the unmatched string.

Comment: @Chrisftw That won't be straightforward with `nomatch`. I think you'll require something like `v1 <- match(unlist(df), m1); df[] =ifelse(is.na(v1) & !is.na(unlist(df)), unlist(df), value[v1])` in that case.

Answer (score 2):

This should also works

```
> m<-apply(df,2,function(x) match(x,match))
> df2<-as.data.frame(matrix(value[m],ncol =ncol(df),nrow=nrow(df)))
> df2
       V1      V2      V3   V4
1    Good    Stop Average  Bad
2     Bad Average    Stop Good
3 Average    Stop     Bad Good
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` with `match`.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) value[match(x, match)])
df
#   V1   V2      V3   V4
#1 Good Stop Average  Bad
#2  Bad <NA>    Stop Good
#3 <NA> <NA>    <NA> Good
```